# GAE For Java: Mail API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

I have developed an application that sends out  mails and SMS. My question is How to send well formatted mails using Google App Engine for Java, Please suggest me anyone.

Thanks,
Abhijit

Answer (score 6):

You send the e-mails using [GAE mail service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/overview.html), of course.

If you're asking about formatting, one way to do it is with a [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) template.  This will give you a nice mail merge feature as well: populate the template with values from a database and send out your messages.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to duffymo's answer you could try [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) or [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) that are other well supported and well documented Java Templating Libraries.